# Heroku giving me a 503 error but works on localhost

Tags: angularjs, heroku

My /register is working perfectly on localhost but giving me a 503 error on heroku. Here's the error message.

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

Here's the next message that appears below it (not sure if it's important or just shows that the app is breaking)

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: error in registerError, Duplicate key: string: , Duplicate value: " "
```

And finally here's my heroku logs

```
2015-12-02T13:44:53.965876+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/modules/aggregated.css" host=www.fillinfor.me request_id=54d7e7b0-037e-4147-a55b-4d66a838b2d8 fwd="69.23.66.60" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=127


2015-12-02T13:45:00.776609+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/register" host=www.fillinfor.me request_id=359d5d68-a083-4349-b4f6-c0198259d0e3 fwd="69.23.66.60" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

Update:

Here's the registration page url http://www.fillinfor.me/?#!/join

here it is on localhost http://localhost:3000/?#!/join

Comment: can you please add both url's 1. localhost and 2. heroku in question details?

Comment: Sure thing @PankajBadukale Thank you!